# Как "перехватить" сигнал с сервера и перенастроить на своё значение?

Tags: javascript

Предположим, что я нахожусь на странице mysite.ru/login, где, нажав на кнопку "Войти", я активирую login() в javascript. В login() идёт отправка сигнала на страницу mysite.ru/data/access, в котором написано {"status":false}. Как мне сфальсифицировать этот "статус" в браузере Google Chrome (хотя бы визуально)?
Через замену url в js в кэше браузера не получилось.

Comment: что за _сигналы_ имеются ввиду? Что значит _сфальсифицировать статус_?

Comment: Если вы контролируете сервер, то установите нужное значение `status` на сервере, если контролируете клиент, то для эмуляции подменяйте значение при разборе ответа на клиенте.